# PANDAS splitting a column by comma delimeter with unknown number of column splits

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called Weather that I want to split into multiple columns

```
(degrees, humidity, wind_mph, wind_chill)
```

It appears like this:

Sometimes it has humidity and sometimes it has windchill, and sometimes it does have one or neither.

```
'81 degrees, wind 8 mph' .  
'40 degrees, relative humidity 75%, wind 17 mph' .   
'52 degrees, wind 12 mph'   
'51 degrees, relative humidity 82%, wind 6 mph, wind chill 0'
```

I want to split so that it will be `NULL` where there is no windchill or humidity in the column splits.

How can i do this?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? How did it end up in that column? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Basically you can use str.extract to extract the desired columns.

```
import pandas as pd
weather = ['81 degrees, wind 8 mph',   '40 degrees, relative humidity 75%, wind 17 mph','52 degrees, wind 12 mph', '51 degrees, relative humidity 82%, wind 6 mph, wind chill 0']
df = pd.DataFrame(weather, columns = ['weather'])
df.head()
df['degrees'] = df.weather.str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*degrees',expand = True)
df['humidity'] = df.weather.str.extract(r'humidity\s*(\d+)%',expand = True)
df['wind_mph'] = df.weather.str.extract(r'wind\s*(\d+)\s*mph',expand = True)
df['wind_chill'] = df.weather.str.extract(r'wind\s*chill\s*(\d+)',expand = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat(
    [df,
    df['ColName'].str.extract(r'(?P<degrees>.*degrees).*(?P<wind_mph>wind.*mph)', expand = True),
    df['ColName'].str.extract(r', (?P<humidity>.*humidity.*%)'),
    df['ColName'].str.extract(r'.*(?P<wind_chill>wind chill .*)'),
    ], 
    axis = 1)
```

You can do a series of extractions with regex and concat them back to your original df. Replace `'ColName'` with the name of the actual column.